# How many customers have placed an order in the last month but also none in the previous 3 months?

Tags: ssas, mdx

I want the count of "reactivated" customers for every country, which placed an order in the previous month (for example Sep 2014) but also placed no orders in the previous 6 months (Mar->Aug 2014).

An example with `AdventureWorks` would be highly appreciated. I have Customer Count over Calendar Years on Columns. How do I get the count of "reactivated" customers (Country on rows) with sales in 2008 but no sales in 2006->2007?!

Adventure Works Example 
http://de.tinypic.com/r/125q7hi/8

Comment: Why do you have to do this with MDX?  Seems like SQL would be a better approach.

Comment: @TabAlleman if the environment is `OLAP` based then `MDX` is the correct choice

Comment: please provide the `MDX` script you are struggling with

Comment: @whytheq Ok, but you can't build an OLAP environment without a relational DB underneath it.   I'm saying OP is probably better off querying the underlying relational tables than trying to get the desired results with MDX and OLAP.

Comment: @TabAlleman ok - why bother having a developer build the `OLAP` cubes if the administrator is just going to query the underlying database?

Comment: @TabAlleman I agree with you that a SQL script is simpler, but I have to get this info out of an existing cube and display it inside this specific BI tool where I can use only MDX.

Comment: @hojtad once the penny starts to drop with `MDX` then an `MDX` solution will be simpler - just a matter of perspective - it'll definitely be shorter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Except` works quite quickly for this scenario. Find all customers who had sales in 2008 then exclude any of those customers who had sales in 2006/2007. This leaves the customers who have sales in 2008 but not 2006/2007.

I played with using the `Filter` function but it was very slow.

There will be a solution using `IIF` with `null` values as one of the return values that will be quick but I can't figure it out.

```
WITH 
  MEMBER MEASURES.[Returning Customers] AS 
    Count
    (
      Except
      (
        NonEmpty
        (
          [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS
         ,
            {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]}*
            {[Date].[Calendar Year].&[2008]}*
            [Customer].[Customer Geography].CurrentMember
        )
       ,NonEmpty
        (
          [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS
         ,
            {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]}*
            {
              [Date].[Calendar Year].&[2006]
             ,[Date].[Calendar Year].&[2007]
            }*
            [Customer].[Customer Geography].CurrentMember
        )
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
    [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS
  * 
    MEASURES.[Returning Customers] ON 0
 ,{[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].MEMBERS} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  [Date].[Calendar Year].&[2008];
```

Your scenario was very specific - so there is no point displaying any year other than 2008.

Here is a great reference as a place to start investigating to returning customer scripts:
http://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/counting-new-and-returning-customers-in-mdx/

I think, in terms of performance, named sets should be used sparingly but when using set based functions they can actually increase performance so maybe, because we are using `Except` named sets might speed things up:

```
WITH 
  SET [2008customers] AS 
    NonEmpty
    (
      [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS
     ,
      {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} * {[Date].[Calendar Year].&[2008]}
    ) 
  SET [20062007customers] AS 
    NonEmpty
    (
      [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS
     ,
        {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]}
      * 
        {
          [Date].[Calendar Year].&[2006]
         ,[Date].[Calendar Year].&[2007]
        }
    ) 
  MEMBER MEASURES.[Returning Customers] AS 
    Count
    (
      Except
      (
        [2008customers] * [Customer].[Customer Geography].CurrentMember
       ,
        [20062007customers] * [Customer].[Customer Geography].CurrentMember
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
    [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS
  * 
    {
      MEASURES.[Returning Customers]
     ,[Measures].[Customer Count]
    } ON 0
 ,{[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].MEMBERS} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  [Date].[Calendar Year].&[2008];
```

This is a more general version of your original problem. Rather than naming the years it looks at customers from the current year in the table who are not found in the previous 2 years:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER MEASURES.[Returning Customers] AS 
    Count
    (
      Except
      (
        NonEmpty
        (
          [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS
         ,
            {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]}*
            {[Date].[Calendar Year].CurrentMember}*
            [Customer].[Customer Geography].CurrentMember
        )
       ,NonEmpty
        (
          [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS
         ,
            {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]}*
            (
              [Date].[Calendar Year].CurrentMember.Lag(1)
            : 
              [Date].[Calendar Year].CurrentMember.Lag(2)
            )*
            [Customer].[Customer Geography].CurrentMember
        )
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
    [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS
  * 
    {
      [Measures].[Customer Count]
     ,MEASURES.[Returning Customers]
    } ON 0
 ,{[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].MEMBERS} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  NULL : [Date].[Calendar Year].&[2008];
```

Trying to figure out what happened in 2006?!